# Etymology of "oblivion"

Tags: etymology

From etymonline, in "oblivion", "ob-" means "over, and "levis" means "smooth", so how does the word have the meaning of  "lacking conscious awareness, not informed about, not aware of something"?

Also does "levis" relate to "levi" which means light, and raise, e.g. elevate, levity?

Comment: Not sure what your real question is here. You've already looked on etymonline where it says the original meaning was to smooth over or even out (as in ‘obliterate’). A mental smoothing out is not that hard to imagine as a euphemism (or just paraphrasing, really) of forgetting something. The _levis_ that means ‘smooth’ is related to the word ‘slime’; it is not the same as the _levis_ that means ‘light’—this is, unsurprisingly, related to the word ‘light’ (and lever, elevate, levitate, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

It's from Latin *oblivio*, meaning 'forgetfulness'.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question very thoroughly—that's only the first direct step, not the actual _etymology_ of the word.

Comment: OK. It’s from Anglo-Norman and Middle French ‘oblivion’ meaning ‘forgetfulness’  and its etymon classical Latin ‘oblivio’ . That in turn is from the verb stem found in ‘oblivisci ‘, to forget. ‘Oblīviscī in turn is from  ‘ob’ + an extended form of an Indo-European base. There is probably a connection with Latin ‘levis’, Greek λεῖος, meaning, as OP surmised, ‘smooth’.

Comment: Etymonline derives it from *levis*, suggesting an incised stone or wax tablet which has been erased by smoothing. OED and Short derive it from *liv-*, meaning "dark", as in *livid*--thus, a "darkened" memory.

Comment: Actually it's from Latin _liveo, lividus_ 'be of a leaden color; blue'. _Obliviscor_ (the deponent inchoative form of _ob + liveo_) means 'to come to have the mind darkened, to forget'.

Comment: Lewis and Short trace 'obliviscor' to ‘livere’, ‘to become dark, hence, to have the mind darkened, forget’, which chimes with John’s account.

Comment: Yeah, same verb; _livere_ is the `Inf`, _liveo_ is the `1sPres`, _livui_ is the `1sPerf`.

Comment: Ok, so what's new. Etymonline seems to have almost said as much, though in a concise way. The OP only had to exercise his mind further and infer the process of evolution from 'smoothing over' or 'blackening over' to 'going obscure' or such.

Comment: Anyway, this SE is about English, not Latin.